# 4-color to 3-color polynomial reduction

Tags: complexity-theory, reference-request, np-complete, reductions

I know a simple reduction from 3-color to 4-color. But how do you reduce 4-color to 3-color ?

I have been searching for the right way to make this reduction for a while now. I would love some pointers.

Comment: There isn't necessarily a "nice" reduction that stays purely within  graph theory.  There might be nothing more intuitive than something like "reduce 4-colourability to 4-SAT, reduce that to 3-SAT and then reduce 3-SAT to 3-colourability."

Comment: I do need the "not so nice" graph transformation. ;)

Answer (score 5):

For a more general reduction, László Lovász [1] proved that

> COLORABILITY reduces to 3-COLORABILITY

The COLORABILITY problem is defined as follows:

> *Input:* A graph $G$ and a positive integer $k$.
>
> *Problem:* Is $G$ $k$-colorable?

That is, the reduction given by László Lovász is applicable to any $k$ ($k \ge 4$).

However, this reduction *is* quite intricate. You can find an excellent explanation [by Vašek Chvátal here](http://users.encs.concordia.ca/%7Echvatal/notes/color.html). Please free feel to ask if you have some difficulty in understanding this reduction.

---

[1] [Coverings and coloring of hypergraphs](http://www.cs.elte.hu/%7Elovasz/scans/covercolor.pdf), Proceedings of the Fourth Southeastern Conference on Combinatorics, Graph Theory, and Computing, Utilitas Math., Winnipeg, Man., 1973.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a summary of the solution of the homework problem for the "New CS 473" class in Spring 2015 at UIUC (Question #4 [here](https://courses.engr.illinois.edu/cs498dl1/sp2015/solutions/hw1sol.pdf)).

Let a 4-coloring consist of colors $\{0, 1, 2, 3\}$, and $\{0, 1, 2\}$ for a 3-coloring.

For any graph $G = (V_G, E_G)$, construct a new graph $H = (V_H, E_H)$ such that:

- $H$ has one "ground vertex" $x \in V_H$.
- $\forall v \in V_G$, create a "vertex gadget" which consists of vertices $v^{+}, v^{-}$ such that $(v^+, x), (v^-, x) \in E_H$, but $(v^+, v^-) \notin E_H$. In a 3-coloring, $v^+, v^-$ are either colored 0 or 1. There are 4 valid states, which correspond to the different colorings of $v \in V_G$.
- $\forall (u, v) \in E_G$, create an "edge gadget" in $H$, which consists of 7 vertices: $a^+, b^+, c^+, a^-, b^-, c^-, d$, and create the following edges (each item is a vertex, and has an edge to each of the vertices in the list after the $\rightarrow$). I duplicated edges for lower items that are already presented in higher items for ease of verification by the reader.

  - $x \rightarrow v^+, v^-, u^+, u^-, d$
  - $u^+ \rightarrow a^+, x$
  - $u^- \rightarrow a^-, x$
  - $a^+ \rightarrow b^+, c^+, u^+$
  - $a^- \rightarrow b^-, c^-, u^-$
  - $c^+ \rightarrow a^+, b^+, d, c^-$
  - $c^- \rightarrow a^-, b^-, d, c^+$
  - $d \rightarrow x, c^+, c^-$
  - $b^+ \rightarrow a^+, c^+, v^+$
  - $b^- \rightarrow a^-, c^-, v^-$
  - $v^+ \rightarrow b^+, x$
  - $v^- \rightarrow b^-, x$.

If $H$ is 3-colorable, then any 2 vertex gadgets connected by an edge have different states. If $u^+, v^+$ are the same color, then $c^+$ is the same color $\rightarrow d$ must be colored 0 or 1, so either $c^+, c^-$ has the color of $x \rightarrow$ either $v^+, u^+$ are not the same color, or $v^-, u^-$ aren't $\rightarrow$ we have created a proper 4-coloring of $G$.

If $G$ is 4-colorable, then $\forall u \in V_G$, give color 0 or 1 to the corresponding vertices in $H$ such that $u.color = 2 \times u^+.color + u^-.color$. Therefore, each edge gadget has a valid 3-coloring (can see that 3 of $\{u^+, u^-, v^+, v^-\}$ are the same color, or 2 of them are color 0 and the other 2 are color 1). Therefore, this is a proper 3-coloring of $H$.

Therefore, $G$ is 4-colorable $\Leftrightarrow$ $H$ is 3-colorable.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a construction that does the reduction.

See diagram:
[image]

The idea is to construct a graph that is 3-colourable iff an original graph is 4-colourable. So, replace each node by a pair of nodes. Add one instance of 3 nodes, completely connected, forcing all three colours to be there, RGB. For a given XY edge, the construction will be colourable in 3 colours iff X!=Y.

A, F, E and J will be either B or R (4 combination matching to 4 colours in the original graph). C will be non-A, and H will be non-F. D can only be G if A!=E. I can only be G if F!=J.

Hence there's D or I being G only if X != Y. But you need D or I being G in order to color K and L. So, if you can colour the construction below, X and Y are of two different colour, for a given coding of the four colour in pairs of (R,B).

It follows that if you can colour the whole resulting graph in 3 colours, after apply the same construction to all edges, you can also colour the original graph in 4 colours.

=======
Previously suggested reading:
(which yes, was a weak answer)

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/294674/polynomial-time-reduction-at-least-as-hard-as-3-color-and-4-color

Comment: It does not really answer my question. I am looking for a polynomial reduction from 4-color to 3-color, not 3-color to 4-color (I know that one already).

Comment: Do you just want to show 4-color to be NP-complete, or are you actually looking for the specific reduction ?

Comment: The specific reduction.

Comment: The linked question doesn't seem very relevant at all.

Comment: If the poster had wanted to show NP-completeness by showing reductions both ways, it would have been relevant.

Comment: @Corathy Ok, found a "not so nice" graph transformation